# How to detect when a connected BLE device change its name?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using Bluetooth low energy to exchange data with an electronic card. During the data exchange, the card can sometimes change its device name to a new one, I am looking a way too detect when this name is modified.

I store the name and the MAC address of this device whhen I connect to the device at the beginning but it seems that android don't see that the name of the deviceas changed. Actually, when I triedto read the name it return me the old name andnot the new one.

this example is called at every data exchange with the electronic card, and every time, it return me the old name, even after the card change its name :

```
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT);
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            Log.i("BLE_device_name : ",device.getName());
        }
```

Is there any listener for this ? Or a method to force Android to get the real BLE name and not the memorized one ?

The only solution I see is to make a new Bluetooth scan but it's too long for my process..

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't connected, you can issue a scan and check the advertisement data what the name is (if it is included).

If you are connected, you can read the GATT characteristic containing the name.

Comment: The problem is that the GATT characteristic that contain the device name is not refresh with the new name until the BLE SoC is reboot. But if I try to reboot the SoC, I loose my connexion to it..

Comment: When you read a GATT characteristic in Android, you always send a read request to the peripheral (no cache or similar is used on the Android side). So per definition if your peripheral doesn't update the name characteristic value until you reboot the peripheral, the name of the peripheral doesn't get update until you reboot.